# Fire javascript function after all xval validations in MVC

Tags: javascript, xval

I want to fire a JavaScript function when the user clicks on a button.

This JavaScript should fire only after the page does the xval validation.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to run only if the form is valid or it doesn't matter?  If you want to run it only if the form is valid try this...

```
<form method="post" id="formToValidateID" >
    <input type="button" onclick="ButtonClicked();" />    
</form>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ButtonClicked() {
        if($("#formToValidateID").validate.form(){
           ExecuteJavascriptMethodIfValid();
        }
     }

    function ExecuteJavascriptMethodIfValid() {
        /* awesome code */
     }
</script>
```

If you don't care if the form is valid, you can leave off the if condition.